# Build Pipeline failing due to "forbidden, inner error code"

Tags: python-3.x, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a simple Python web app (just displays a message).  I am unable to create a build pipeline due to an (apparent) authorization issue.  The message is:
Failed to set Azure permission 'RoleAssignmentId: [**removed**]' for the service principal '[**removed**]' on subscription ID '**[removed]**': error code: Forbidden, inner error code: AuthorizationFailed, inner error message The client '[**my Azure Account ID**]' with object id '**[removed]**' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write' over scope '/subscriptions/**[removed]**' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials. Ensure that the user has 'Owner' or 'User Access Administrator' permissions on the Subscription.

I am creating a brand new build pipeline and selected 1) Azure Repo, 2) then selected my simple Python program which is checked in, 3) then selected Python to Linux Web App on Azure, 4) then selected my subscription, 5) then selected my Azure Web App (already set up), 6) then selected validate and configure.

I believe my account was set up with the requisite permissions so I am wondering whether this is really my subscription or is this another problem?  Can anyone shed light on what is happening?

Any help would be appreciated.  Thx.

Answer (score 0):

For your current situation, we recommend you can check the below info:

1. Are you creating an Azure Resource Manager service connection using automated security? If yes, please know that the you need to signed in as the owner of the Azure Pipelines organization and the Azure subscription. Please refer the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops#create-an-azure-resource-manager-service-connection-using-automated-security).
2. We recommend you can try to create a new ARM service connection manually. Please follow this [doc](http://Create%20an%20Azure%20Resource%20Manager%20service%20connection%20with%20an%20existing%20service%20principal).
3. Also, you can ask your Azure subscription owner to create a new ARM and test if it will work well.
4. You can follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/webapp-linux?view=azure-devops&tabs=dotnet-core%2Cyaml) to help you configure your yaml file to deploy the Azure Web APP.

Comment: Thank you, Yujun.  It was a permissions problem on the part of the person who set up my account.  All is resolved. Thank you for the info - I still went through it.

Comment: Hi @JohnDuncan,  You could accept your comment as an answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks. If not, please let us know if you would like further assistance. You can refer this doc to help you know how to accept the answer(https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)